# Ngspice: printing a lot of reference values instead of running the simulation

Tags: spice, ngspice

I have a project that uses ngspice as a shared library. I fed a SPICE file to this project and the same file to ngspice.exe. The ngspice.exe finished execution within seconds, however, the sharedlibrary goes on and on forever; it just keeps printing "Reference Value".

[image]

I have tried using the shared library with the same project before and it worked perfectly. This behavior started out of the blue. Could someone elaborate as to what is going on and why ngspice.exe does not print this?

Answer (score 0):

That printout should happen only every 0.5 second or 
so, not at every internal timestep. Maybe you did 
something to the time/date keeping functions, or 
provided a wrong ticker value?

-marcel

Comment: The only change between the working and the non-working project was that I experimented with ngGet_Vec_info. Apart from this, there hasn't been any other change. I reverted this experimental code but that didn't solve either. If I have inadvertently messed up the time/date keeping functions, why would that be persistent across executions?

Comment: what is a wrong ticker value?

Comment: I have had no luck fixing it. I have gone through the manual and the code a fair number of times now and I can't find a solution. Any help would be a godsend

Answer (score 0):

There is no "out of the blue".

ngspice shared library does not print anything. All communication is handled via the api.

Probably you intermixed *.o files from ngspice exe with *.o files from ngspice shared library.

Do at least a 'make clean' before you switch from making the exe to making the shared lib.

If that does not help, do a fresh checkout from git.

Comment: I have cleaned and rebuilt but no luck. I deleted the entire include folder and reloaded my old one but that doesn't help either

Comment: It got fixed now and I didn't change a thing. I sure did hope to find some issue since if it arose again I could have fixed it but alas.